# Bootstrap toggler button not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap into reactjs but my toggler button not working. I didn't add the scripts of jquery becuase I'm importing bootstrap at the top. It should appear and work only on small devices.

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const Navbar = () => {

    return (
<div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
                <div className="container">
                    <a className="home-style navbar-brand" href="/">PORTFOLIO</a>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarNav"
                        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <a className="btn-style nav-item nav-link" href="/">HOME <span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            <li >
                                <a className="btn-style nav-item nav-link" href="/about">MY STORY</a>
                            </li>
                            <li >
                                <a className="btn-style nav-item nav-link" href="/work">WORK</a>
                            </li>
                            <li >
                                <a className="btn-style nav-item nav-link" href="/projects">PROJECTS</a>
                            </li>
                            <li >
                                <a className="btn-style nav-item nav-link" href="/contact">CONTACT</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </nav>

        </div>
)
}

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: Bootstrap's dynamic features use JavaScript (mostly jQuery), but since you're using React, you should just use a react lib that implements Bootstrap, like [_reactstrap_](https://reactstrap.github.io/).

Comment: _"I didn't add the scripts of jquery because I'm importing bootstrap at the top"_, you're only importing Bootstrap's CSS.

Comment: ok I add the scripts from bootstrap with React.Fragement 
but still not working

Comment: Like I said in my first comment, I recommend you use an implementation of Bootstrap in React and avoid jQuery altogether. It's just going to give you more problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to import Jquery in index.js. Also using react-bootstrap without Jquery worked. Thanks for everyone

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/. I recently built a simple little app and used this to avoid issues using bootstrap with React.

The code looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./App.css";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import MediaQuery from "react-responsive";
import SpotifyWebApi from "spotify-web-api-js";
import { Base64 } from 'js-base64';

import Jumbotron from 'react-bootstrap/Jumbotron'
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'


<div className="App">
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                            <Col className = "autoCenter">
                                <Jumbotron className = "backgroundColor">
                                  <h1>Hello, friend!</h1>
                                  <div>
                                    Hello
                                  </div>
                                  <div className = "mt3">
                                   text
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                    <Button
                                        className="spotifyGreen mt4 f6 dim br-pill"
                                        href = "">
                                            button
                                    </Button>
                                  </div>
                                </Jumbotron>
                            </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
</div>
```

I left out a bunch of stuff, but hopefully that helps with the syntax!

Comment: is react-bootstrap more smooth than bootsrap4?

Comment: @Mahmoudnafea it is bootstrap 4, but implemented with React, so that you don't have to.

Comment: @Mahmoudnafea Please just click the link and read it, it should provide answers to most of your questions, but I believe this package will do what you want.